# Are there any matlab toolbox or software to simulate diffusion in social network graph?

Tags: graph, matlab, sna

**I have a dataset of a directed graph like this:**

-Directed graph (each unordered pair of nodes is saved once): CA-HepTh.txt 
   -Collaboration network of Arxiv High Energy Physics Theory category (there is an edge if authors coauthored at least one paper)
   -Nodes: 9877 Edges: 51971

-FromNodeId   ToNodeId

24325   24394

24325   40517

24325   58507
....

**I need a software or a matlab toolbox to simulate diffusion and define influenced nodes, based on an initial set of nodes.**

Answer (score 0):

i've never tried it but maybe it can help you. http://www.levmuchnik.net/Content/Networks/ComplexNetworksPackage.html

They simulate diffusion processes in complex networks.

Best,

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.